# Why are de-selected and deleted Mods still appearing?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

See below. I de-selected the "Active Mods" with a red circle and exclamation mark. Why they still appearing on the right?

You can't see, but I deleted some them (as .scs files) from my computer.

[image]

Comment: When you removed them, did you confirm the changes?

Comment: @smock yes yes yes

Comment: Did you remove them from the active list on the right though?

Answer (score 1):

Bit unintuitive: it isn't sufficient just to check/uncheck them on the left panel, you have to also move them to/remove them from the "active mod" list to the right using the arrow buttons (and you can pick the load order too).